# Regex to extract http links from an XML file

Tags: regex

I have an xml file with many lines like:

`<xhtml:link vip="true" href="http://store.vcenter.com/stores/en/product/tigers-midi/100" />`

How do I extract just the link - `http://store.vcenter.com/stores/en/product/tigers-midi/100`?

I tried `http://www\.\.com[^<]+` but that captures everything untill the end of the line - including quotes and closing XML tags.

I'm using this expression with egrep.

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: openSUSE GNU/Linux

Comment: `http[s]:\/\/.*\.com[^"]+`

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for that. When I try on the command line `egrep -o "http[s]:\/\/.*\.com[^"]+"` and press enter I get `>` on a new  line. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), use a proper XML/HTML parser.

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
You can use one of the following :

- `xmllint`
- `xmlstarlet`
- `saxon-lint`

File:

```
<root>
<xhtml:link vip="true" href="http://store.vcenter.com/stores/en/product/tigers-midi/100" />
</root>
```

Example with `xmllint` :

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[@vip="true"]/@href' file.xml 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
 href="http://store.vcenter.com/stores/en/product/tigers-midi/100"
```

If you need a quick & dirty one time command, you can do:

```
egrep -o 'https?://[^"]+' file
```

Comment: I'm getting `warning: failed to load external entity "/@href"`

Comment: Added grep solution if it's a one time usage. If you want to use a parser correctly and having trouble, better post the input file

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'll play with these options and see if I can make it work. the grep command somehow breaks my terminal emulator - enter doesn't execute the command, but opens a new line...

Comment: Looks your term is broken, seems nothing to do with the grep. Try `reset` command in term